# An elliptic differential operator is Fredholm, References for differential operators

Tags: complex-geometry, differential-operators

In Voisin's book on complex geometry, volume 1, page 128 she states that an elliptic differential operator is Fredholm. Her reference (Demailly 1996) is in French.

My question is: 
Is there a reference of this statement (with proof) in English or Russian?

An extra question: 
Voisin's treatment of differential operators is less than satisfactory (for me). If you could point out a reference for differential operators, the symbol of differential operators and a calculation of the symbol of the Laplacian, which is concise but illuminating, I would be very glad.

Comment: You could look at the book "Principles of Algebraic Geometry" of Griffiths and Harris, zero chapter. It deals with the laplacian and I think it'd be a good complementary book to Voisin's. Many modern books on harmonic analysis contain something about symbols, but they are not concise. Try "Fourier Analysis" of "Duoandikoetxea", section "An operator algebra". For symbols in manifolds, maybe the books of Hörmander on linear PDE, but this is far from concise. I don't recall a short and illuminating reference.

Comment: Try the Paper "The Uncertainty Principle" of Fefferman (1983), first chapter, it is quite illuminating about symbols and that stuff.

Comment: W. Ballmann - *Lectures on Kähler Manifolds*, Chapter 1 and Appendix C for a good introduction to Differential Operators on Complex Manifolds; R. O. Wells Jr. - *Differential Analysis on Complex Manifolds*, Chapter IV "Elliptic Operator Theory" (clear title).